# How to get available Vaadin Charts for developing

Tags: eclipse, charts, widget, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I am trying to develop with **Vaadin Charts**, but I am not I am not able to install it.

The documentation says: "*Once you have installed the library in your project, you need to compile the widget set*". I installed the library without problems using Maven, but after that I don't know what to do. If I try to execute some code I receive an error like that:

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation
```

I have been reading the documentation but I'm a little lost. I read about creating a `Vaadin widget Eclipse project` but then I don't know how to connect with a simple `Vaadin Project`...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to make a widget project, just a normal vaadin project, then add the addon you need and compile the widgetset. Look here for more details on how to integrate them: https://vaadin.com/de/book/-/page/addons.html

Comment: Here is one of my doubts! how can I compile the widgetset from a Vaadin project??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a good Vaadin Tutorial that speaks about widgetset and some addons:

> If the add-on contains a custom client-side widget, as is the case for
>   most UI component add-ons, it is required to create and compile the
>   widgetset before running the application. When using the
>   'vaadin-archetype-clean' archetype, you first need to uncomment the
>   relevant sections in your 'pom.xml' (gwt-maven-plugin and
>   vaadin-maven-plugin configuration sections as well as the dependency
>   on GWT and the snapshot plugin repositories). Then see the Directory
>   Help page for detailed instructions.
>
> To automatically find added widgets at a later time, run the goal
>   'vaadin:update-widgetset' and to recompile the widgetset after
>   updating client-side widgets or Vaadin, execute the goal
>   'gwt:compile'.

To sum up, basically you must add to your build goals the nexts one:

```
vaadin:update-widgetset

gwt:compile
```

And automatically the corresponding `<inherit>` tags will be added to your `*gwt.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like you didn't add your *.gwt.xml to web.xml

Read this document: https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons/maven